# Stop processing on Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-batch

I'm quite newbie to Spring Batch and I'm having some problems.
I have a spring batch step, which has a reader, a chain of item processors with 2 processors and a writer. I'd like to stop the second processor from running when the first finishes with error.
I've tried using a StepExecutionListener returning ExistStatus.FAILED but no success. I've also tried adding a ItemProcessListener to do some action on the onProcessError method, but nothing.
Any ideas on how can I do that?

Here is the code I'm using to configure the step.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemProcessor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class StepConfig {

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private ItemReader<String> flatFileItemReader;

    @Autowired
    private ItemWriter<ResponseTO> itemWriter;

    @Bean
    public Step buildStep() {
              return stepBuilderFactory.get("step")
                .<String, ResponseTO> chunk(1)
                .reader(flatFileItemReader)
                .processor(chainOfItemsProcessors())
                .writer(itemWriter)
                .faultTolerant()
                .build();
    }

    private CompositeItemProcessor<String, ResponseTO> chainOfItemsProcessors() {
        CompositeItemProcessor<String,ResponseTO> compositeProcessor = new CompositeItemProcessor<>();
        List<ItemProcessor<?, ?>> itemProcessors = new ArrayList<>();
        itemProcessors.add(processor1);
        itemProcessors.add(processor2);
        compositeProcessor.setDelegates(itemProcessors);
        return compositeProcessor;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure the error is thrown in the first item processor and not in the reader?

Comment: what you are asking for should be the normal composite behaviour, A composite acts as single object so if first processor fails, next processors in chain are skipped.